# Asus Chromebox Displayport monitor not detected

Tags: multiple-monitors, asus, chromebook, displayport

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 as a dual boot OS on my Asus Chromebox and I'm a linux newbie.

Anyway, everything seems to be working fine except for the DisplayPort monitor not working.  The Chromebox has two outputs - DisplayPort and HDMI.  I have a HDMI -> DVI cable as well as a DisplayPort -> DVI adapter hooked to a DVI cable.  Both monitors work fine in ChromeOS mode, but only the HDMI port works in Ubuntu mode.

I went to the display settings in ubuntu but only the HDMI-connected monitor is showing up. I have swapped the cables to hook into each different monitor but only the HDMI one works no matter the setup.

Also, if I only hook up the DisplayPort and boot into Ubuntu, it does show a little bit of text for a second before it goes into graphical mode and then the monitor loses signal. So I'm guessing it's a missing driver or something.
Is there some way to see if I have a missing driver or something that would be needed to detect this second monitor?

Thanks

Comment: You can edit your question to add details like that, it's a little easier to follow that way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.  I was using a passive DP to HDMI adapter which worked with Chrome but not Ubuntu or Arch.  Switched to an active adapter and it came right up.

Comment: Same here, +1 for active adapter

Answer (score 1):

I have the same, first tried with an active HP DP->DVI, and with a direct cable. Both don't work out of the box. You  can force a connection like this:

```
xrandr --addmode DP1 1280x1024
xrandr --output DP1 --mode 1280x1024 --right-of HDMI1
```